# In Perl, how can a subroutine get a coderef that points to itself?

Tags: perl

For learning purposes, I am toying around with the idea of building
event-driven programs in Perl and noticed that it might be nice if a
subroutine that was registered as an event handler could, on failure,
just schedule another call to itself for a later time. So far, I have
come up with something like this:

```
my $cb;
my $try = 3;
$cb = sub {
    my $rc = do_stuff();
    if (!$rc && --$try) {
        schedule_event($cb, 10); # schedule $cb to be called in 10 seconds
    } else {
        do_other_stuff;
    }
};
schedule_event($cb, 0); # schedule initial call to $cb to be performed ASAP
```

Is there a way that code inside the sub can access the coderef to that
sub so I could do without using an extra variable? I'd like to
schedule the initial call like this.

```
schedule_event( sub { ... }, 0);
```

I first thought of using `caller(0)[3]`, but this only gives me a
function name, (`__ANON__` if there's no name), not a code reference
that has a pad attached to it.

Comment: If you are doing this a lot in the same run of the program, you will have a memory leak due to the circular reference. You can use Scalar::Util::weaken() to avoid this, or use Sub::Current or the Y-combinator as suggested below. See http://use.perl.org/~Aristotle/journal/30896 for a discussion. If this code is not in a persistent environment, your code above is likely fine.

Comment: runrig: Thanks for the link. My head is spinning now. :-) Maybe I'm actually going to learn something...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`__SUB__`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__SUB__.html) has been added in 5.16, providing this usability.

Answer (score 14):

I think [Sub::Current](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sub::Current) will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, apparently this does what I want. Too bad it needs to poke around in Perl's internals to do that...

Answer (score 14):

To get a reference to the current subroutine without using an extra variable, you can use a tool from functional programming, the Y-combinator, which basically abstracts away the process of creating the closure.  Here is a perlish version:

```
use Scalar::Util qw/weaken/;

sub Y (&) {
    my ($code, $self, $return) = shift;
    $return = $self = sub {$code->($self, @_)};
    weaken $self;  # prevent a circular reference that will leak memory
    $return;
}

schedule_event( Y { my $self = shift; ... }, 0);
```

Comment: Is this correct? I'm not sure what $curry is for. At first I thought my answer was different, but now I think your 3rd "$curry" should be "$code" and you should ditch the $curry. And this answer I think would give you a circular reference with a memory leak.

Comment: @runrig => if you only pass the original code ref into the sub, then any subsequent calls using that ref will no longer receive the coderef as their first argument.  There was a circular reference in the code I had.  I have updated it to correct the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I got it about 5 minutes after I walked away. I've updated my answer too :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't change `$cb`'s value again, you can use that.  If not, define a scalar to hold that and don't change it ever again.  For example:

```
my $cb = do {
  my $sub;
  $sub = sub { contents using $sub here }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a fixed-point combinator, you can write your $cb function as if the first argument was the function itself:

```
sub U {
  my $f = shift;
  sub { $f->($f, @_) }
}

my $cb = sub {
  my $cb = shift;
  ...
  schedule_event(U($cb), 10);
  ...
}

schedule_event(U($cb), 0);
```

Comment: your second call to `schedule_event` will not be passed a copy of $cb that receives itself as its first argument.  I've updated my answer to show a version that doesn't leak memory anymore.

Comment: You're right, a callback function is being passed to another function instead of just getting called from the sub, so the sub needs to be wrapped every time. Updated.