# How do I get a reference to a function from within the function?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Perl, how can a subroutine get a coderef that points to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554214/in-perl-how-can-a-subroutine-get-a-coderef-that-points-to-itself)

Is there a way to get a reference to a function from within that function *without* using the name?

I've recently found myself repeatedly writing code that smells of an anti-pattern. [Data::Dump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dump) supports filters but (as of version 1.16) they aren't applied recursively. To work around that I've been writing things like this:

```
sub filter {
    my ($context, $node) = @_;
    # ...
    return { dump => dumpf($something, \&filter) };
}
```

This works, but the `\&filter` reference is starting to bug me. It creates maintenance overhead if the function is renamed or copied elsewhere as a template for a new filter. I'd like to replace it with something like `__SUB__` (if Perl had such a thing).

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554214/in-perl-how-can-a-subroutine-get-a-coderef-that-points-to-itself ??

Comment: @runrig: Excellent. I could have sworn there was a similar question here but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

For named subroutines you can use `caller` to get the name and then take a reference to it:

```
sub foo {
    state $self = \&{(caller(0))[3]};
    #...
    # call $self->();
}
```

This doesn't work for anonymous subroutines, which get "names" like `main::__ANON__`.